# AS3: Importing classes/Sharing variables between classes

Tags: actionscript-3, class

Ok, this is my problem: i have a variable in a class named Mirror

```
public var line:Sprite = new Sprite();
```

i want to use that variable in another class named MovieClip. I imported the class in the MovieClip class:

```
   public class MovieClips extends MovieClip
{
    import Mirror;
    public function MovieClips(radius:int, _x:int, _y:int,size:int,span:int,addl:Array) 
    {....
```

but when i try to do something like this:

```
if (Mirror.line.hitTestObject(ball) == true) {
                    speedY *= -1;
                }
```

It shows up like an  error: Acess of a possibly undefined property line through a reference with static type Class. I'm not sure what did i do wrong? Am i importing my class in the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass your `Mirror` object to your `MovieClips` object like in the following example:

```
package {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        }// end function

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            var mirror:Mirror = new Mirror();
            var movieClips:MovieClips = new MovieClips(mirror);

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package

import flash.display.MovieClip;

class Mirror extends MovieClip {

    public var line:MovieClip;

    public function Mirror():void {

        line = new MovieClip();

    }// end function

}// end class

class MovieClips extends MovieClip {

    public function MovieClip(mirror:Mirror):void {

        mirror.line;

    }// end function

}// end class
```

Also you could improve on this by making `Mirror.line` read only:

```
class Mirror extends MovieClip {

    private var _line:MovieClip;

    public function get line():MovieClip {

        return _line;

    }// end function

    public function Mirror():void {

        _line = new MovieClip();

    }// end function

}// end class
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a class, like `Mirror` and do something like `Mirror.line` , that means you're trying to access a static class variable named line.  Static variables/method are tied to the class, and not an instance of that class.

You haven't defined line as a static variable and thus you get the error.
I'm not sure you want it to be a static variable though and most likely you are just confusing the `Mirror` class for a instance of the `Mirror` class.

Somewhere you are likely creating an instance of your Mirror class:
`var myMirror:Mirror = new Mirror()` or dragging an instance on a timeline if using FlashPro (and then could give it an instance of 'myMirror' as an example).

You would access `line` on the instance of a Mirror class. so with the above it would be `myMirror.line`.

Importing a class does not give you access to any instances of that class, so if you want to be able to access an instance of `Mirror` from within your `MoveClips` class, you'd need to pass in a reference to it, or use the `parent` keyword to get to the right scope (so if your Mirror instance and your MovieClips instance are on the same timeline/parent, you could do `Mirror(MovieClip(parent).myMirror).line` - assuming your parent is of type MovieClip).

---

If you did want it as a static variable, just add the static access modifier to it's definition.

```
public static var line:Sprite
```

Keep in mind though that static variables are always in memory regardless of if you have any instances of them made.